# What is the difference between personal consumption expenditure price and PCE quantity?

Tags: macroeconomics, industrial-organisation, definition, input-output

What is the difference between these two things? How is PCE price different from PCE quantity? Also, I am confused about the difference between PCE quantity and measure of real output. For example, what is the difference between PCE quantity and Industrial Production?

Answer (score 4):

Personal consumption expenditure (PCE) is the primary measure of **consumer spending** on goods and services in the U.S. economy.   It accounts for about two-thirds of domestic final spending, and thus **it is the *primary engine* that drives future economic growth**.  PCE shows how much of the income earned by households is being spent on current consumption as opposed to how much is being saved for future consumption.
https://www.bea.gov/resources/methodologies/nipa-handbook/pdf/chapter-05.pdf

The PCE price index is a measure of the prices that people living in the United States pay for goods and services. The PCE price index is known for capturing inflation (or deflation) across a wide range of consumer expenses and reflecting changes in consumer behavior.

[https://www.bea.gov/data/personal-consumption-expenditures-price-index#:~:text=A%20measure%20of%20the%20prices,reflecting%20changes%20in%20consumer%20behavior.](https://www.bea.gov/data/personal-consumption-expenditures-price-index#:%7E:text=A%20measure%20of%20the%20prices,reflecting%20changes%20in%20consumer%20behavior.)

Most PCE price indexes are derived by extrapolating consumer and producer price indexes from the U.S. Bureau of Labor Statistics.

**The PCE quantity index** derived by deflating current-dollar estimates at the most detailed category level by appropriate PCE price indexes with the reference year equal to 100.

Prices and quantities are prepared at a detailed level and are aggregated based on a Fisher chain-weighted formula  https://www.bea.gov/sites/default/files/methodologies/nipa-handbook-all-chapters.pdf#page=64

This source can provide some answers: https://www.bea.gov/help/faq/521

The difference **between PCE quantity and industrial production** is that PCE come from consumer spending.   Industrial production measures the output of the industrial sector, which typically comprises mining, manufacturing, utilities and, in some cases, construction.

**The difference between PCE quantity index and real output** is that PCE come from consumer spending while Real output comes from spending from consumers, business/industries, and government/government enterprises.